# Authenticate client application with Azure Active Directory

Tags: wpf, authentication, azure, active-directory, azure-api-apps

Good Day!

I'm trying to configure my Azure API App in such a way that it can only be accessed by trusted application by using Azure AD (Public Authenticated). I created entities inside the AD for a WPF application and my API app. I gave the entity of my WPF app permissions to have access to my API app. I use the following method to access my API.

```
        public Task<string> COGetOrganisationsAsync()
        {
            if(adAuth == null) adAuth = new coADAuthentication(ClientID, RedirectURL, Authority, ResourceURI);

            string token = adAuth.AcquireTokenOrRefresh();

            using(HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                Uri requestURI = new Uri(new Uri(Authority), "Organization/GetAll"); 
                HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), requestURI);
                var req = httpClient.PostAsync(requestURI, httpRequest.Content).ContinueWith(httpResponseMessage =>
                {
                    return httpResponseMessage.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                });

                return req.Result;
         }
```

I successfully receive a valid token which I add to the header. My req.Result in the following message

> {   "status": 403,   "source":"https://serviceplan-resourceg01234567890abcdef.azurewebsites.net/MyMethod/GetAll",
>   "message": "Permissions for service \"myService\" are set to public
>   auth but no authentication was associated with the request." }

The status 403 tells me that the server did receive my request but it is Forbidding.. The code is working fine, because when I change the authentication to public i receive correct data.

I'm not sure if my Azure AD is configured correctly, but I've been looking for a solution for days now.The Azure documentation is scattered, outdated or not useful for my particular scenario.

My question is, does anyone else have the same issues and can anyone perhaps suggest me some useful documentation?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This is not limited to WPF either.  I've tried Cordova ADAL plugin and also windows console .NET app.  Same result.  Tested API App for authentication direct from browser with success.  x-zumo-auth header has a token which I can use from angularjs app $http, again a successful call is made.  The accessToken received from ADAL using native application's client id is way bigger than x-zumo-auth header - don't know if that is relevant - and when I use that token like so "Bearer <token>" I get the 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry you have trouble finding what you need. App Service API Apps have support out of the box for many providers that you just have to enable and configure at the gateway. Then the services living behind the gateway will have authentication and they will all share the same authentication providers (if of course they are configured as Public authenticated) so a caller of API App A, won't have to re-authenticate to access API App B.

You can find a step by step guide at [Protect an API app: Add Azure Active Directory or social provider authentication](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-add-authentication/)

Having said that, what that the article that caused confusion or was outdated? We're trying to make these articles as discover-able as possible, so any feedback will help us improve.

Answer (score 0):

API app platform abstract the authentication of an API app using a "zumo token". The idea is that no matter which authentication provider you want to use, like AAD, Facebook, Google, Twitter or Microsoft Account, it will be (mostly) transparent to your client code. The general flow is

1. You configure the gateway which manages your API app to use the auth provider you want. In your case, AAD.
2. You ask the users to login at https:///login/aad
3. This will put the AAD token into the gateway and return a zumo token
4. Your client code then get the zumo token and use it to call the API app

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-dotnet-add-authentication/ as pointed out by Panagiotis has the details.

Comment: I've used this URL for my own application already, unfortunately without success. I'll try to review the steps taken, perhaps i missed something. I'll keep in touch. 

Thanks for the information